# The field polls.UserProfile.user was declared with a lazy reference to 'polls.user', but app 'polls' doesn't provide model 'user'

Tags: python, django, django-models

So I've been using the website:

https://www.fomfus.com/articles/how-to-use-email-as-username-for-django-authentication-removing-the-username

To build a section of my project, but I keep getting the error:

```
ValueError: The field admin.LogEntry.user was declared with a lazy reference 
to 'polls.user', but app 'polls' doesn't provide model 'user'.
The field calendarium.Event.created_by was declared with a lazy reference to 
'polls.user', but app 'polls' doesn't provide model 'user'.
The field calendarium.Occurrence.created_by was declared with a lazy 
reference to 'polls.user', but app 'polls' doesn't provide model 'user'.
The field filer.Clipboard.user was declared with a lazy reference to 
'polls.user', but app 'polls' doesn't provide model 'user'.
The field filer.File.owner was declared with a lazy reference to 
'polls.user', but app 'polls' doesn't provide model 'user'.
The field filer.Folder.owner was declared with a lazy reference to 
'polls.user', but app 'polls' doesn't provide model 'user'.
The field filer.FolderPermission.user was declared with a lazy reference to 
'polls.user', but app 'polls' doesn't provide model 'user'.
The field polls.UserProfile.user was declared with a lazy reference to 
'polls.user', but app 'polls' doesn't provide model 'user'.
```

My App name is called polls, I've made sure that 'polls' is installed in my settings.

```
 AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'polls.User'
```

To tell Django that this is the model I want to use. My models.py looks like this:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser, BaseUserManager
from django.db import models
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _


    class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
        """Define a model manager for User model with no username field."""

        use_in_migrations = True

        def _create_user(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
            """Create and save a User with the given email and password."""
            if not email:
                raise ValueError('The given email must be set')
            email = self.normalize_email(email)
            user = self.model(email=email, **extra_fields)
            user.set_password(password)
            user.save(using=self._db)
            return user

        def create_user(self, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
            """Create and save a regular User with the given email and 
            password."""
            extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', False)
            extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', False)
            return self._create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)

        def create_superuser(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
            """Create and save a SuperUser with the given email and password."""
            extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
            extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)

            if extra_fields.get('is_staff') is not True:
                raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_staff=True.')
            if extra_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
                raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_superuser=True.')

            return self._create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)
 
    class User(AbstractUser):
        """User model."""

        username = None
        email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)

        USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
        REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

        objects = UserManager()
```

Can anyone provide any clarity on why this might be? And provide a solution as well?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like your app name is `polls.User` with a capital U. But your reference to this model in the app `calenderium` model `Event` field `created_by` is `polls.user` with a small u. I cannot recreate the problem with the information you gave so can you please try fixing that and get back to me?

Comment: That wasn't the issue but thank you anyway :)) Managed to fix it

Comment: @EthanPearce It would really useful if you could post your solution. I am also having this problem.